# I want to apply (50000,32,32) mask to the dataloader (50000,32,32,3)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I made the siliency mask shape with torch.Size([50000, 32, 32])

How should I apply this to the original dataset shape with (50000, 32, 32, 3)

I'm tryint to do the change the original dataloader's dataset

> original dataset(50000,32,32,3) x mask(50000,32,32)

but the becasue of the shape difference I have no idea how to apply

Comment: can you please elaborate? what are you trying to do? what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: tryint to edit the original dataloader's dataset with mask

Comment: What do you mean by that? please edit your question to reflect what you have tried and what *exactly* is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Element-wise multiplication is only possible for broadcastable (tensors with compatible shapes). It means that ranks (number of dimensions)  should be equal and each dimension should be equal for both tensors, or one (or both) of them can be 1. So all you need is add empty dimension in place of channel for mask. Your mask will have shape `(50000,32,32,1)` and you'll be able to multiply:

```
result = dataset * mask[:, :, :, None]
```

or [np.expand_dims()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) implementation:

```
result = dataset * np.expand_dims(mask, axis=3)
```